# Connected components in the plane

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I would greatly appreciate if you could give some reference to my question.

There compact set $K$ for which $\mathbb{C}\setminus K$ have to have infinite connected components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a Cantor set and rotate it so that each of its points becomes a circle. That's $K$.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a Kantor set in the real line, and join each of its points to $i $ and to $-i$.

Alternatively, consider the union of all circles of center 1/n and radius 1/n.